# how to force TeX to keep line breaks?

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I would like to write a programme code to a file, so that it can be later on executed. The language requires to keep line breaks.

```
\begin{myCode}
one
two
three
\end{myCode}
```

In my macro I have following

```
\obeylines
```

which produces this output:

```
one^^Mtwo^^Mthree
```

Is there a simple way how to replace `^^M` by a line ending character that would by recognized by a Unix system? I understood that `verbatim` environment processes text line by line, but in this case it's probably not necessary.

**Update:**

Here's the minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{environ}

\newwrite\myOutput
\makeatletter

\def\my@writeToFile#1{
  \immediate\openout\myOutput=output.txt%
  \immediate\write\myOutput{#1}
  \immediate\closeout\myOutput
}

\newenvironment{myCode} {
    \obeylines
    \Collect@Body\my@writeToFile %macro from the environ package
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{myCode}
  one
  two
  three
  \end{myCode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example with the code that gives the problem.

Comment: If you want to write the code to a file as ASCII text you should consider using the `filecontents` package.

Comment: How is the `MyCode` environment defined? In particular, what is the `\dospecials` macro supposed to achieve?

Comment: sure, I've added a minimal working code. `\dospecials` is useless there, I guess. I'll have a look at the `filecontents` package

Answer (score 4):

```
\newlinechar`\^^J
```

will make it put unix line end control J at the ends instead of control M,

Comment: where should be this defined? I wasn't able to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of an important fact: `\write` expands its argument during the writing operation. So (leaving out, for the moment, the line termination problem) if your environment is

```
\begin{myCode}
\emph{x}
\end{myCode}
```

the result in `output.txt` will be the not very amusing

```
^^M\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \def myCode{x}\let \futurelet \@let@token \let \protect \relax \protect \relax \protect \edef n{it}\protect \xdef \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 {\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 }\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \size@update \enc@update x\egroup ^^M
```

Verbatim writes to files is available, for example, with the package `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{output.txt}
one
two
three
\emph{x}
\end{VerbatimOut}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, I understand it's not very universal solution

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46040/162451), using `\newlinechar` to let `^^M` be interpreted as a new line character in your new environment seems to work.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{environ}

\newwrite\myOutput
\makeatletter

\def\my@writeToFile#1{
  \immediate\openout\myOutput=output.txt%
  \immediate\write\myOutput{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\myOutput%
}

\newenvironment{myCode} {
    \newlinechar`\^^M%
    \obeylines%
    \Collect@Body\my@writeToFile% %macro from the environ package
}{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myCode}
one
two
three
\end{myCode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I now realise that David probably ment to replace `\obeylines` with `\endlinechar=`\^^J%`. This works as well (and is simpler)

Answer (score 0):

based on [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill)'s advice I've tried `filecontents` package. I came up with following solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{myCode}[1] {
    \filec@ntents{#1}
}{%
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begin{myCode}{myFile.txt}
one
two
\emph{txt}
\\ dangerous $ code %@# 
\end{myCode}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

```
%% LaTeX2e file `myFile.txt'
%% generated by the `myCode' environment
%% from source `test' on 2012/02/28.
%%
one
two
\emph{txt}
\\ dangerous $ code %@#
```

It's minimalistic, but it does pretty much what I wanted (just remove those comments and it will be perfect).

Comment: `\@tempswafalse\filec@ntents{#1}` will remove the comments. There are also spurious spaces in your code.

Comment: @egreg those comments go away if you use `filecontents*` of standard LaTeX, so no need for lowlevel hackery here ;-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Yes, but the OP wants to define a differently named environment. I really don't know why using `myCode` would be better than `filecontents*`, nor why the more powerful facilities of `fancyvrb` are not exploited.

Comment: hmm, I just wonder why we made those `filecontents` environments preamble-only. So that is why Scott wrote the package. Maybe not a good idea to have this restriction.